# Shell - Delete files in directory after 3 months

Tags: shell, ksh

All,

I need to delete files within a directory past a certain date.  I have a function with format:

Example file: `my_test_file_2015_04_01.log`

Example function
`rem_files $my_directory my_test_file_*.log`

How would I remove all files after 3 months?

`function rem_files
{
    ?????????
}`

Comment: Do you have to use the date in the filename, or can you use the file's modification time?

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust file, "modified time" you can use `find -name my_test_file_*.log -ctime +90` to find files older than 90 days

Comment: Note that `ctime` is not "creation time", but "time of last change". Many/most Linux/Unix file systems don't make "creation time" readily available, if they even track it at all...